# Memory node of device tree in /proc doesn't match dtb

Tags: linux, u-boot, device-tree, arm64

I'm trying to modify the memory node in a device tree for a zynqmp zcu102 board. However, something seems to be overriding this node somehow.

I'm booting using a FIT image and u-boot. I've confirmed the FIT image has the correct DTB by its shasum and that the kernel is using the right DTB by adding a fake node which shows up in /proc/device-tree. However, for some reason the memory node as shown in /proc/device-tree doesn't match the DTB.

Here's the relevant section of my device tree:

```
memory {
    device_type = "memory";
    reg = <0x0 0x0 0x0 0x10000000>;
};
fakenode{
    foo = "bar";
};
```

Here is what I see in those nodes in /proc/device-tree:

```
root@zynqmp:/proc/device-tree# hexdump memory/reg
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0080 0000
0000010 0000 0800 0000 0000 0000 0000 0080 0000
0000020
root@zynqmp:/proc/device-tree# hexdump memory/name -C
00000000  6d 65 6d 6f 72 79 00                              |memory.|
00000007
root@zynqmp:/proc/device-tree# hexdump fakenode/name -C
00000000  66 61 6b 65 6e 6f 64 65  00                       |fakenode.|
00000009
root@zynqmp:/proc/device-tree# hexdump fakenode/foo -C
00000000  62 61 72 00                                       |bar.|
00000004
```

Is there some way that u-boot or the linux config can override the memory node during boot? I'm at a loss right now what to do next.

UPDATE:

I've found that linux is inheriting the /memory node in u-boot's own device tree. I'm not sure if this is documented anywhere, I discovered it experimentally. Is there a way to decouple these?

Comment: I changed my u-boot device tree to the different memory node and linux's changed too. So I guess that it is inheriting it from u-boot.